# Laptop won't boot after Windows 10 update (No HDD activity, No Display and Won't even show BIOS screen)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

My laptop had problems before I installed windows 10. But before I install the latest update that I downloaded windows warned me that my device may be risked because it is out of date but I still proceed in installing the update. After installing it I attempted to turned my laptop but it doesn't boot anymore, it also does not display anything on the laptop's monitor and won't even show the BIOS splash screen (totally black screen, no LCD/Monitor activity) but the Hard Disk Drive light is on for just 3 to 4 seconds and then turns off after that.

Things I tried to fix it:

- Removed the RAM Sticks and CPU and reconnected them again (To make sure that there are no problems with them because I removed them a week ago as I cleaned my laptop)
- Removed the laptop's battery and tried to turned on
- Turned on the computer for not less than 12 hours (in hope that it is just installing something)
- Removed both RAM Sticks (2 4GB RAM Sticks, total of 8 GB) and heard a continuous loud beep sound (Signifies that there's no problem in Motherboard)

What should i do to fix this problem and what does it caused?

P.S. A few days ago I clean it's motherboard and it's components (RAM, CPU, HDD, etc.). could this be the problem? It also makes a click sound when it turns off.

Comment: "Removed the[...] CPU and reconnected..." New thermal paste? "clean it's motherboard and fan" .. best bet is you've ham-fisted something in all that. Either re-do it all, carefully, or give it to a professional.

Comment: I just cleaned the motherboard and all of its component. maybe I removed the CPU's thermal paste. It makes a click sound when it turns off

Comment: Something inside is fried. If you are qualified, check the motherboard and CPU for broken links or overheat-related issues. If not, then give it to a professional.